# Why am I receiving "incorrect" output in this ifelse statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I am new to python and trying to learn by doing small projects.

I am trying to write a program that displays the names of the four properties and
asks the user to identify the property that is not a railroad. The user should be informed if the selection is correct or not.

```
properties = "Reading,","Pennsylvania","B & O","Short Line"
question = str(input("Which is not a railroad?")) **Short Line**
if properties == "Short Line":
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

However, my final output shows as "incorrect", what am i doing wrong?

The four railroad properties
are Reading, Pennsylvania,
B & O, and Short Line.
Which is not a railroad? Short Line
Correct.
Short Line is a bus company.

Comment: You might want to compare agaist `question`.

Comment: @KlausD., post as an answer, man! Get those up-votes.

Comment: @SpencerD There are fruits hanging *too* low.

Comment: Not too low for me

Comment: @KlausD., lol fair enough ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things I see with this code you have posted.

First, not sure if you actually have `**Short Line**` in your actual code but if you are trying to comment use #   That way it won't be interpreted at run time.

Second as mentioned in other answers you are checking against properties which is pulling in your array. You should be checking against your input which is stored at question.

```
properties = "Reading,","Pennsylvania","B & O","Short Line"
question = str(input("Which is not a railroad?")) # **Short Line**
if question == "Short Line": # replaced properties with question
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
print(properties)
print(question)
```

I find that when I am having troubles understanding why something is not working I throw some print statements in to see what the variables are doing.

Comment: Yes, **Short Line** is the input.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to catch the user in a loop, otherwise you would have to constantly have to run the code to find the correct answer(unless that is the desired behavior, then you can leave it as you have it). Also, be aware that you may want to uppercase or lowercase because a user may provide the answer as "Short line" (lower case "L"), and the code will return as incorrect. Of course, that depends on what you will accept as an answer.

Sample

```
print ("Reading,Pennsylvania,B & O, or Short Line. Which is not a railroad?")
user_input = input("Please provide an answer: ")
# != the loop will close once the user inputs short line in any form
# The upper.() will convert a user_input string to all caps 
while user_input.upper() != "SHORT LINE":
  print ("Incorrect, Please try again.")
  user_input = input("Which one is not a railroad? ")

print ("Correct")
```

Answer (score -1):

Prettied it up for you

```
print( "Reading, Pennsylvania, B & O, and Short Line. Which is not a railroad?" )
print("Which is not a railroad?")
answer = input()
if answer == "Short Line":
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Comment: Made it uglier.